# How to solve bazel build error in Docker Build?

Tags: deep-learning, dockerfile, bazel, mozilla-deepspeech

This error keeps on coming during docker build.

Tried various code techniques.

```
ERROR: Process exited with status 128: Process exited with status 128
++ git describe --long --tags
+ tf_git_rev=v1.14.0-14-g1aad02a78e
+ echo 'STABLE_TF_GIT_VERSION v1.14.0-14-g1aad02a78e'
+ pushd native_client
++ git describe --long --tags
fatal: No names found, cannot describe anything.
+ ds_git_rev=
STABLE_TF_GIT_VERSION v1.14.0-14-g1aad02a78e
/tensorflow/native_client /tensorflow
INFO: Elapsed time: 150.094s, Critical Path: 6.47s
INFO: 1 process: 1 local.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
The command '/bin/sh -c bazel build --workspace_status_command="bash native_client/bazel_workspace_status_cmd.sh" --config=monolithic --config=cuda -c opt --copt=-O3 --copt="-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0" --copt=-mtune=generic --copt=-march=x86-64 --copt=-msse --copt=-msse2 --copt=-msse3 --copt=-msse4.1 --copt=-msse4.2 --copt=-mavx --copt=-fvisibility=hidden //native_client:libdeepspeech.so //native_client:generate_trie --verbose_failures --action_env=LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Build should be successful.

Comment: attach your dockerfile, the problem is probably there

Comment: I met the same question as yours.

Comment: I could reproduce this error in Docker running on Windows 10. I had no issues on an  Ubuntu-Box.